# Watch OS 3 app installs on Watch Series 2 and Not on Watch Series 1

Tags: ios, iphone, watchkit, apple-watch

I have developed a Watch app, an extension for my existing iPhone app. The environment used to develop the app is as follows

- Xcode 8.3.2
- Swift 3.1
- Deployment target 3.0 (For watch)

I have **Series 2 simulator** and two **Series 2** devices - where the app works as expected without any issues. And I am using an **iPhone6s Plus (ios 10.3.3)**

On a watch **Series 1 (watch OS 3.2.3 and iPhone 6s with iOS 10.3.3)**, which is at a different location has a problem with installation. The watch app installation halts/stops at the end of its progress and doesn't move further.

Tried all workarounds suggested below (including reset of watch and the iphone) but none worked.

[Link 1](https://www.imore.com/how-fix-stuck-apple-watch-app-install), [Link 2](https://www.igeeksblog.com/how-to-fix-app-got-stuck-on-apple-watch/), [Link 3](https://discussions.agilebits.com/discussion/47132/watch-app-wont-install-stuck-on-installing)

Am I missing something obvious in the **project setup** or **info.plist** or any settings that supports a Watch Series 1? Please help.

Comment: Can you install the app on a Series 1 simulator?

Comment: haven't tried that. How can I get Series 1 Simulator? Can't see it in List of simulators to download :|

Comment: oh wait. if it doesn't show Series 2, then is it actually a Series 1?

Comment: Try it with the original Watch Simulator (the one that doesn't have Series 2 in its name). Series 1 has the exact same hardware as Series2, so it shouldn't matter. Judging from this fact, your installation error seems to be an error with the device itself and not a setup issue on your project side.

Comment: @DávidPásztor: I just tested, and it works on Series 1 simulator very well - as in my Series 2 simulator and watch. 
Do you have any more ideas other than the links in my question, by any chance? :-)

Comment: Sadly I don't have any other ideas why your particular device is unable to install the app. You might want to move your question to apple.stackexchange.com, since it is about a problem with a specific hardware and not a programming issue.